# unity3d rotation issues involving sphere gravity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

So in unity 3d i have come across using a character controller to rotate the player game object with the 3d gravity system i am using. here are the scripts:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent (typeof (Rigidbody))]
public class GravityBody : MonoBehaviour {

    public GravityAttractor attractor;
    private Transform myTransform;

    void Start () {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().useGravity = false;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().constraints =
            RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotation;
        myTransform = transform;
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
        if (attractor) {
            attractor.Attract (myTransform);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider col) {
        GravityAttractor obj = col.GetComponent ("GravityAttractor") as
        GravityAttractor;
        if (obj) {
            attractor = obj;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit (Collider col) {
        attractor = null;
    }

}
```

and:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class GravityAttractor : MonoBehaviour {

    public float gravity = 0;
    public float rotationSmoothness = 5f;
    public float density = 5.52f;
    private float volume;

    public void Start () {
        if (gravity == 0) {
            if (GetComponent<Collider> ().GetType () == typeof (SphereCollider)) {
                volume = (GetComponent<Collider> ().bounds.size.x * Mathf.PI) / 6;
            } else if (GetComponent<Collider> ().GetType () == typeof (CapsuleCollider)) {
                volume = ((Mathf.PI * GetComponent<Collider> ().bounds.size.x * GetComponent<Collider> ().bounds.size.y) * GetComponent<Collider> ().bounds.size.z) / 4;
            } else {
                volume = GetComponent<Collider> ().bounds.size.x * GetComponent<Collider> ().bounds.size.y * GetComponent<Collider> ().bounds.size.z;
            }
            gravity = -((density / 10) * volume) / 2;
        }
    }

    public void Attract (Transform body) {
        Vector3 gravityUp = (body.position - transform.position).normalized;
        Vector3 localUp = body.up;

        body.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddForce (gravityUp * gravity);

        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation (localUp, gravityUp) * body.rotation;
        body.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (body.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSmoothness * Time.deltaTime);
    }

}
```

the issue is that whenever i try to add in the standard unity third person controller issues arise when the character tries to rotate [as seen in this video](https://i.gyazo.com/8098f390013eb3581adab321c79f6e65.mp4)

If anyone knows what to do i would appreciate any help.
(i am using the most recent unity version)

Comment: Could you please explain how the character **should** be rotating? The video isn't too clear.

Comment: There is also the chance that your script and the third person script are both trying to rotate the player based on mouse input and your gravity calculations, resulting in this problem.

Comment: I had figured it out, it was an issue that was easy to solve by making a new character controller (or rather using the one that was included in the project for the gravity.) and adding the quaternion for the rotation based on the player input to the one responsible for the orientation to the planet: 

`  rotation = (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * 5f);
  player.transform.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0f,rotation,0f * Time.deltaTime);`